# How to copy paste as raw csv from formatted csv file using LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: csv, libreoffice, copy-paste, libreoffice-calc, selection

Given a raw csv file:

```
$ cat foo.csv 
foo, bar
buzz, "quoted string"
```

[image: Libre office calc text import with separator and text delimiter set]

If I open this one with Libre Office with these settings, I can view it nicely. Yet if I select the entire document again and copy it, the clipboard contains:

```
foo  bar
buzz    quoted string
```

I was expecting the clipboard to restore the raw csv again.

---

The example is very contrived, yet background is that I want to only export a sub fraction from a larger csv without having to cherry-pick via `sed` or using

```
head -n 1 > example.csv
cat large.csv | grep SOME_CODE >> example.csv // sometimes the filter is not as easy
```

I like to use LibreOffice Calc as it offers a nice filter feature through `Data > Autofilter` making it easy to find the lines I want to use. Yet extracting that selection is not as straightforward.

I will use the smaller file for setting up a unit test, which is why I don't want to change the format of the csv file even if it most likely wouldn't make much of a different given a proper csv parser.

As the point of the unit test is to make sure it parses the actual format properly, and I don't want to test against LibreOffice's understanding of a CSV file.

How can I maintain the raw formatting when copying from a CSV file in LibreOffice Calc?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Autofilter, use *Data -> More Filters -> Standard Filter* and copy results to Sheet2.

[image: standard filter]

Then from Sheet2, go to *File -> Save As* with type `Text CSV` to produce the following file.

```
foo,bar
```

This is slightly different formatting from the original.  If it needs to be exactly the same, then LO Calc is not the right tool.  Use `sed` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Paste it into a sheet,make sure it is all selected then go to Data > Text to Columns. This will open the same dialog that you see when importing a .csv file.

(I'm on Libreoffice 4.3.2.2 btw)